# history.go(-1) cannot work in IOS14 Beta2 App

Tags: history, ios14

My web app is working in a WebView of an IOS native application. There is a button on the top-left side of the page, and it will go back to the previous page after the button is clicked. So far so good, but recently many customers have upgraded their IOS to 14 Beta2 and now the back button doesn't work as expected.

I use the history.go(-1) to go back, but if the session history length is 2, it will execute the history.go(-1), but the page will not go back. The url also doesn't change. If the user continue to open new page, then it works again.

Does anyone have ideas of whats going on with it?

Comment: It's a beta, looks like you've found a bug. Report it with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet the same problem. You can use setTimeout delay for a while when you use history.push，like this

```
 setTimeout(() => {
       history.push('xxx');
 }, 100);
```